# What set are these bags from? bearded mini-fig head, tan, dark tan, maroon, white and black bricks, some small black windows

Tags: set-identification

I picked up two sealed bags up from the church thrift store. Markings are 2017, 515R8, 13149, bag numbers 3 and 4, Each bag has at least one flesh colored, bearded mini-fig head, tan, dark tan, maroon, white and black bricks, some small black windows. Can anyone identify the set?

[image: bearded mini-fig head, tan, dark tan, maroon, white and black bricks, some small black windows]
[image: bearded mini-fig head, tan, dark tan, maroon, white and black bricks, some small black windows]

Answer (score 9):

I am no expert brick sleuth, but I see a white [Dinosaur Tail End Section / Horn](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40379&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) and a dark tan [4x12 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3029&idColor=69#T=C&C=69), which I believe narrows this to [**75930-1 Indoraptor Rampage at Lockwood Estate**](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75930-1). That set apparently has six bags total, so if that is correct you're indeed missing most of it.

Comment: That seems to be correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Based on the

- Black [Window 2 x 6 x 2 Train Front / Boat](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=17454&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)
- Dark Red [Slope 75 2 x 2 x 3 - Solid Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3684c&idColor=59#T=C&C=59)
- White [Dinosaur Tail End Section / Horn](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40379&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

these bags should be from

[75930: Indoraptor Rampage at Lockwood Estate](https://brickset.com/sets/75930-1/Indoraptor-Rampage-at-Lockwood-Estate)

[image]